# Context cancelled by timeout but computation is not aborted?

Tags: go, goroutine, go-context

Trying to understand how go context cancellation will abort execution of subsequent code

Details of experiment:

1. main func has a context that times out in `2sec`
2. main func calls another func `sum` in a separate go-routine - which sleeps for `1sec` for test-run-1  & `4sec` for test-run-2
3. letting main sleep for `3sec` to let spun go-routine complete execution

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    c := context.Background()
    childCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(c, 2*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    go sum(5, 6, ch)

    var msg string

    select {
    case <-childCtx.Done():
        msg = "return from ctx done channel"
    case res := <-ch:
        msg = fmt.Sprintf("return from go routine: %v", res)
    }

    log.Print(msg)

    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) //sleeping here to test if go-routine is still running
}


func sum(x int, y int, c chan<- int) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) 
    //testcase-1: sleep - 1s
    //testcase-2: sleep - 4s

    result := x + y

    log.Printf("print from sum fn: %v", result)

    c <- result
}
```

Response for testcase-1 : sleep sum function for 1 sec:

```
2021/04/12 01:06:58 print from sum fn: 11
2021/04/12 01:06:58 return from go routine: 11
```

Response for testcase-2 : sleep sum function for 4 sec:

```
2021/04/12 01:08:25 return from ctx done channel
2021/04/12 01:08:27 print from sum fn: 11
```

In testcase-2 when sum func sleeps for 4 secs, context is already cancelled by timeout after 2secs, why is it still executing the sum func in diff go-routine and printing `print from sum fn: 1` ?

From documentation: [Canceling this context releases resources associated with it.](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithTimeout)

My assumption is that all the computation will be aborted immediately after 2 secs including the spun go-routine

Let me know how to do this right, thanks in adavance

Comment: Having a context doesn't do anything magic. If you want your goroutine to detect when the context is done, you'll have to have it also try to receive from the channel returned by the context's `Done` method like you're doing in `main`.

Comment: A more general way to put this is: go's goroutines are (and must be) *cooperative*. One goroutine cannot shoot another one in the head to kill it, but one goroutine *can* take some action (such as marking a context as cancelled, or closing a channel) so that the second goroutine can *notice* that the first one has *politely asked* for the second one to quit. You must write that second goroutine to take notice of the polite request.

Comment: Thanks for helping torek & @Andy Schweig

Comment: My understanding of things is little wrong, these comments helped me correct,
For more on this - refer this blog - https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/2018-06-17-golang-using-context-cancellation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @AndySchweig has noted, `context` signals a cancelation event, but does not enforce cancelation. It's up to any potentially blocking goroutine to do its best at trying to cancel/clean-up after it detects a cancelation.

To update your `sum` function to support cancelation you could try:

```
// add context parameter as the first argument
// add a return error - to indicate any errors (i.e. function was interrupted due to cancelation)
func sum(ctx context.Context, x int, y int, c chan<- int) (err error) {

    wait := 1 * time.Second // testcase-1
    //wait := 4 * time.Second // testcase-2

    // any blocking called - even sleeps - should be interruptible
    select {
    case <-time.After(wait):
    case <-ctx.Done():
        err = ctx.Err()
        return
    }

    result := x + y

    log.Printf("print from sum fn: %v", result)

    select {
    case c <- result:
    case <-ctx.Done(): // check for ctx cancelation here - as no one may be listening on result channel
        err = ctx.Err()
    }
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/DuIACxPvHYJ

Comment: can you help me with good soure for learning GO

Comment: @shaara I'm sure you've done the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) - it's always good to repeat it, as there's a lot there that you may miss on first reading. Then there's [Go by example](https://gobyexample.com/). This is another [good resource](https://learn.go.dev/). Finally just code! There's no better way to learn than getting your hands "dirty". Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The context is not gonna abort the go routine. In your case you just don't print the result from the go routine if context's time is out. The go routine doesn't know anything about the context.